# create a list where each line has multiple fields in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, format

I have a script that output this to stdout.

```
FIeld1 field2 = field3
```

there are about 30 files like that 
i want instead of printing this using print.. assigne it to a list

but i do not know how..

I have something like this:

```
data = []
field2 = 'toto'
field1 = 'foo'

for A in some_dict:
   print(field1, field2, "=", " ".join(str(x) for x in A.values()))
```

I have tried with data append and data.extend always get an error

```
for A in aliases:
   data.append(field1 + field2 + "=" + " ".join(str(x) for x in A.values()))
```

but there are no spaces withint the values..

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting

Comment: the issues is that there are no spaces and if i add the spaces by hand i get
`data.append(uid + host + "=" + " ".join(str(x) for x in A.values() + '\n'))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: What would data look like if this works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want to do is something like:

```
for A in aliases:
    data.append(field1 + " " + field2 + " = " + " ".join(str(x) for x in A.values()))
```